# Custom Role Based Authentication For Images and Other Non-aspx Files

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-7

I am trying to have a custom role based on authentication based on this article
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2905/Role-based-Security-with-Forms-Authentication

Aspx files are working fine.

However when I try to access non-aspx files e.g. images I am getting redirected back to the login page.

Any idea?

Comment: Are these in another directory?  Do you have a webconfig for the directory?  Post your webconfig

Comment: web.config is very much similar to that example.